# How to perform missing-block error correction with C#/.NET?

Tags: .net, math

I have a byte array which I can split into *n* blocks. Is there a .NET standard library function that will supply an additional *m* blocks, such that if I later lost up to *m* blocks of the combined *n+m* blocks, a second function could reconstruct the original byte array? (Given the remainging blocks and an indication of which blocks are missing.)

If not the .NET standard library, are there any third-party libraries available?

(I don't want to prejudice answers by suggesting a particular algorithm.)

Comment: I think doing it exactly the way you want is impossible. If I take the extreme example of blocks of size 1 bit and *m* = 1, you can *detect* one bit of error, but not reconstruct the original.

Comment: You could reconstruct it if you know which bit is missing. I'll edit the question to clarify this point. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the method [Utility.EncodeRs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd159671.aspx) which will do [Reed-Solomon Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed-Solomon).

(My memory is a bit rusty, but I believe that adding `m` blocks will allow you to lose up to `m` blocks with RS.)

Note that this is in the .NET micro framework, not .NET standard, so you might need to install something new.